# Shortcut or macro for changing font type in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros

Is there a keyboard shortcut for changing the font in Outlook on Windows? I have to alternate between Calibri and Courier constantly for technical reasons and clicking on the font dialog every time gets very tedious. I know that I can use Ctrl+Space to change anything to the default (Calibri) font.

If there is no shortcut, could someone please help me create a macro to toggle fonts? I imagine I can assign any shortcut to a macro?

Comment: You know, you can *record* macros in Word.

Answer (score 10):

(The answer by techie007 didn't work for me in Outlook 2010)

This macro (adapted from http://www.slipstick.com/developer/word-macro-apply-formatting-outlook-email/) does:

```
Sub SetCodeFont()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection
    On Error Resume Next

    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
            If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
                Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
                Set objWord = objDoc.Application
                Set objSel = objWord.Selection
                objSel.Font.Name = "Consolas"
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Next, in the VBA Editor go to  `Tools > References` and select `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library`.

Now, to create a keyboard shortcut for a macro, add it to your Quick Access Toolbar as follows:

1. Open a new mail message
2. Click on the small drop down arrow on the Quick Access Toolbar (typically located at the top of the window) and select "More Commands..."

[image: more-commands]

3. The Outlook Options dialog will open, then select "Macros" from the "Choose commands from:" dropdown

[image: macros]

4. Select the SetCodeFont macro from the list and press "Add >>"
5. The macro button will now appear on the Quick Access Toolbar

To run the macro highlight some text in your email, and press `Alt + <Num>` where `<Num>` is the position of the macro in your Quick Access Toolbar. For example, if the macro is the first button on the toolbar, use `Alt + 1` to invoke it.

Comment: Where do I find the VBE Editor?

Comment: @Danijel To open the VBA editor, use the short cut Alt + F11. To paste the code above, please use the menu item **Insert** > **Module**.

Comment: Some users may need to select `Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library`.

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, this is the key sequence to focus the Font selector: <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Alt+R doesn't work for me in Word or Outlook.  Alt+H does though (Alt+H, F, F).  Maybe a localization issue (since you're in Germany and I'm in the US)?

Comment: @techturtle: I actually only use English software. Incidentally, I was working in a German VM at the time, so, yes, your analysis is correct :)

Comment: Much easier than a custom macro.  If only I had an equivalent to BetterTouchTool on Windows, I'd be able to set *this* to an arbitrary keybinding directly.

Comment: @Wildcard you can use AutoHotkey to define a single hotkey that will send a different hotkey. E.g. ``~^q::!hff`` means send Alt+H followed by f twice whenever Ctrl + Q is pressed. The tilde says AutoHotkey should allow the Ctrl + Q to be seen by any application.